# pagination next previous button insertion and dot functions

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pagination

```
$sql_result_count = mysql_query ($query) or die ('request "Could not execute SQL query" '.$query);
$row = mysql_fetch_row($sql_result_count);
$total_records = $row[0];
$total_pages = ceil($total_records / 2);

for ($i=1; $i<=$total_pages; $i++) {
          echo '<a href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?startrow='.$i.'">'. $i.'</a>';    
};
```

this is code i did for pagination , it is working fine adn prints pagination number like 1 2 3 4 . here how can i place next and previous button, and how to make it like prevoius 1 2 3..next like pagination

Comment: Simply add a previous and next code block as mention [here](http://www.phpfreaks.com/tutorial/basic-pagination)

Comment: Might be this link is useful http://www.phpeasystep.com/phptu/29.html